# js jest mock classes and static methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I wrote mock for my class and everything works, when I test creating instance, but not, when I test static method. How to fix this?
Here is my testing class:

```
class Order {
    async add(items) {
        const order = new OrderModel({items});
        await order.save();
        //...
    }

    async find(items) {
        const query = OrderModel.find({
            //condition
        });
        //...
    }
}
```

My OrderModel mock:

```
const mockOrderModel = {
    save: jest.fn(),
    find: jest.fn(),
    exec: jest.fn()
};

jest.mock('../order/order.model', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            save: mockOrderModel.save,
            find: mockOrderModel.find,
            exec: mockOrderModel.exec
        };
    });
});
```

And tests for both methods:

```
//WORKS
it('add()', async () => {
    await order.add(['']);

    expect(OrderModel).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockOrderModel.save).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

//NOT WORKS
it('find()', async () => {
    await order.find(['']);

    expect(mockOrderModel.find).toHaveBeenCalledTImes(1);
});
```

OrderModel.find() method is not called

Answer (score 0):

That's because `find` on `mockOrderModel` is defined as a property of an object and not a static method. So basically you're creating a mock object for `Order` with `find` property that must be called on an instance. Static method of `Order` is not mocked. To do so you can try:

`Order.find = jest.fn()`